# DDMS missing columns in allocation tracker

Tags: android, eclipse, ddms

In the DDMS view in Eclipse I'm missing all the columns of the second section of the allocation tracker...

I can see a list with "alloc order" and "alloc size" and such but clicking on any of those items in the list will not give me any more info in the second half of the screen...

In screenshots online I can see that it should tell me which file and even row number is allocating memory, instead I get 4 or 5 items like "at Java.lang.Objec..." ending in ellipsis, but no way to expand that column to show the whole line...

I've rebooted a few times and am using the latest tools, ADT and SDK...

Anyone ever encounter such a problem? It's making hunting down an OOM error very difficult...

Comment: having the same issue on OSX with latest tools

Answer (score 1):

This also happened with me.

The allocation tracker and logcat both had missing columns.

This seems to be happening with IDE with outdated Developer tools.

Make sure you check for updates for the Android Developer tools (https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/)

```
Help > Check for Updates
```

**Current version**

21.1.0.v201302060044

**After that make sure the tools are updates:**

Open Android SDK manager and make sure your SDK tools are up to date.

```
Window > Android SDK Manager
```

And make sure the *Status* columns displays *"Installed"* and not *"Update available"* for The Tools.

Current versions are:

- Android SDK Tools rev. 21.1
- Android SDK Platform-tools rev. 16.02

**EDIT:** I'm terribly sorry. It seems I missed the part where you said you already tried the above. These things worked for me and fixed the problem so I was pretty sure this is the solution.

It seems re-installing Eclipse might be the next step. (Which I never had to do)

Comment: Thanks for the thorough reply. My SDK and platform tools are up to date. My ADT is 21.1.0.v201302060044-569685 which is slightly older than the one you mentioned but still doesn't show up in the update section in Eclipse

Comment: Your ADT version is very up to date, mine was missing a zero. A typo. I'm sorry my answer couldn't help you. And I advice you to re-install Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks again, I'm sure other users with the same problem will solve it with your info. Looks like I'll be re-installing Eclipse...