# issue with the android ddms allocation tracker view at bottom

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ddms

I'm not quite sure how to ask this question so I'll just show a picture of the problem.
[image: DDMS Allocation Tracker screen grab]

Notice in the bottom half of the window it shows the stack trace of where this object was allocated, but it is cut short and there don't seem to be any tabs to slide to make it bigger. I was just wondering if there is a fix or anything.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: having the same problem. really frustrating. seen this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15297955/ddms-missing-columns-in-allocation-tracker but updating the development tools does not help me.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think the way it shows is the only way.

I just downloaded and re-installed the whole SDK and Eclipse. I was having this problem that this is useless, but this is because I am using IntelliJ and not Eclipse, so the DDMS is running as an independent software.

When you use it inside Eclipse, double clicking this trimmed line in allocation tracker would take you to your source code.

So, need to waste some disk space to have Eclipse for this...